# Use of "denote" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

What is wrong in the following sentence?

For an element x of G, denote by o(x) the order of x and x^G the conjugacy class of x in G.

Comment: It's very domain-specific (where mathematics or perhaps some specialism thereof is the domain) and so the conventions of that domain are more important than the rules of grammar.  In other words, it doesn't make any sense in English but it isn't supposed to so it's not relevant.

Comment: I would rather say "let o(x) be the order of x and x^G denote the the conjugacy class of x in G".

Comment: @Graffito: "let o(x) be the order of x and x^G denote the the conjugacy class of x in G" or "let o(x) be the order of x and let x^G denote the the conjugacy class of x in G" ?

Comment: @MehdiRezaei. I also hesitated between both formulations. One may prefer the second one with 2 "let".

Answer (score 3):

Normally, at the very least in mathematics, *to denote* is treated as a transitive verb i.e. it should have a subject (the thing, usually a symbol, that does the denoting) and an object (the thing it denotes). So as already observed above, you should write

''For an element x of G, let o(x) denote the order of x...''

Of course, one can also use *to denote* in passive i.e. switching the subject and the object, and then the above sentence would become

''For an element x of G, the order of x **is denoted by**  o(x)...''

For me, both of these sound perfectly natural.

I believe that something closer to what you have written would make grammatical sense when you use the verb slightly differently: namely taking ''we'' as the subject which is denoting (the object) x **by** (the indirect object) o(x). So

''we denote the order of x by o(x)..''

would be fine. The problem is that you using the verb without a subject, and as such it appears in its imperative form i.e. ''You! Denote x by o(x)!''. This would be fine as an instruction e.g.

''when writing up your proof, denote the order of x by o(x)''

but in a normal article one uses the collective ''we'' rather than the imperative. So I believe that this is ultimately why your original usage of the verb is slightly awkward.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please write the whole sentence? I am not sure about the second part of sentence.

Comment: For an element x of G, let o(x) denote the order of x and x^G [denote] the conjugacy class of x in G. You can usually leave out the second instance [denote] when listing like this.

Comment: How about "Suppose for an element x of G, o(x) denotes the order of x and x^G denotes the conjugacy class of x in G."? Is this correct?